# JAVA REST Resource is executing twice for file downloading

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest

I have the corresponding code to download a zip file by javascript and ajax. In the back-end I use REST resources and Java to handle the request. This is the following js code to download the file

```
var urlDownload = "/test/download/";
$.ajax({
       url: urlDownload ,
       async:true,
       type: 'GET',
       success: function (data) {
            if (data != undefined) {
                window.location = urlDownload;
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, exception) {
           // display the error message
            return true;
        },
        cache: false
    });
   }
```

The following is the corresponding JAVA-REST code to handle the request from UI

```
@Metric(op = "get the file")
@Path("/test/download/")
@GET
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response downloadZIP() {
   System.out.println("Downloading the zip file");
    try{
        / .....
        .......
        Logic to create the zip file and return the FILE object
        ......
        ...... /
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=test.zip");
        return response.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // return an error message
    }
}
```

So, the problem is the print statement is getting executed twice i.e. my entire business logic to create the zip is also getting executed twice. To debug further, I commented out the following line **window.location = urlDownload;** in javascript and I figured out that now it is executing only once but obviously the file is not getting downloaded as the required JS code is commented out.

So, my question is why the REST resource is executing twice?

Is it because the **GET and Download** url is same and as both of them are same URL, so it is getting mapped to the same resource when the request comes from the UI?

Is there any way to bypass it other than creating to different REST resources (two different urls) i.e. one for the **GET** request which will perform all the business logic and the other resource will handle the download part only after the first resource is executed or is there any other way to download file using JS or ajax?

Answer (score 0):

**window.location = urlDownload;** is the programmatical way in javascript to load a new page on the navigator, so what you are doing is
requesting your web service (first call), then entering the address of the web service on your navigator, which will make a second call to load the said web service as a web page.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX GET itself will call the download code. There is no need for window.location = urlDownload. It will again call the same URL second time. Then what is the purpose of AJAX there. Have you checked without window.location = urlDownload and it calls the download code or not ?

Comment: It calls the download code without window.location = urlDownload because of the ajax GET request but to get the download prompt in the browser or to start the download, I need the code "window.location = urlDownload", right?

Comment: Download file totally depends on REST Code what you have written. AJAX or Window.location just calls that Service. So you can use either AJAX or window.location. Why you are using ajax. Just use window.location. As your REST service is of type GET, then it is enough.